# Using preprocessor ## to call a function dynamically

Tags: c

I have a function called `create_car`. I am trying to use a preprocessor macro so that I can call the function by doing `Create(car)`. Here is what I have thus far:

```
#define ObjName(X)  _Generic((X), struct Person: "person", struct Car: "car")
#define NewObj(X)   create_ ## ObjName(X)

struct Car* create_car(void) 
{
   // do something here
}
struct Car {
    char* make;
    char* model;
    int year;
    void (*print)(struct Car*);
};

int main(void)
{
    struct Car *car = NewObj(struct Car);
}
```

But when trying that I get the following error:

```
gen.c:5:21: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘create_ObjName’; did you mean ‘create_car’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 #define NewObj(X)   create_ ## ObjName(X)
                     ^
gen.c:40:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘NewObj’
     NewObj(struct Car);
     ^~~~~~
gen.c:40:12: error: expected expression before ‘struct’
     NewObj(struct Car);
            ^
gen.c:5:40: note: in definition of macro ‘NewObj’
 #define NewObj(X)   create_ ## ObjName(X)
```

What does the issue seem above with how I'm trying to create the object from the macro?

What I'm looking the code to become after preprocessed/compiled is:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct Car *car = create_car();
}
```

Comment: <O/T> please leave this in macro hell where it belongs and use functions.

Comment: Missing definition for _Generic, and I pretty much agree nobody wants to debug this macro pile.

Comment: @Joshua _Generic is a C keyword.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're actually trying to do. You can fix your current problem by adding extra macros to force expansion of macros to happen before pasting, but that won't do what you want. `_Generic` doesn't become a token from a string, it's a compile-time (after pre-processor) thing that will have the value `"person"` or `"car"`.

Comment: Can you please add the output that you desire? i.e. what is the code supposed to look like after it's preprocessed?

Comment: @cigien sure I just updated the question.

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't know anything about types (except as needed to do basic arithmetic in `#if` conditions). At that stage, `struct`, `Car`, and `_Generic` are all just tokens with no related meaning.

Comment: @ThomasJager I see: basically what I'm trying to do is create something that will expand to `create_<objectType>`. In the above I've just included one type (`Car`), but hopefully I could use that to do it with multiple types, such as `create_car`, `create_bus`, `create_airplance`, etc.

Comment: So why not use it as `NewObj(car)`?

Comment: @aschepler sure, whatever works...I just can't get it to work in any manner.

Comment: @David542 To do what was suggested in that comment, all you need is `#define NewObj(X)   create_ ## X`

Comment: @ThomasJager More precisely, `#define NewObj(X) create_##X()` (with the trailing `()`)

Comment: @RaymondChen got it. That's pretty tricky and doesn't add too much to things (I think that was one of the first comments on the question). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Or possibly `#define EXPAND(x) x` and `#define NewObj(x) create_## EXPAND(x)`, if you might want to use a macro within the macro argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it this way. The C preprocessor does not know about `_Generic`. It will treat is a normal name, a potential candidate for further expansion.

However, you could use `_Generic` in definition of NewObj macro.
The issue is the argument of `NewObj(X)` is not a value but a type.
However you can bypass it by dispatching over a NULL pointer to `X`
to find a proper constructor function.

```
#define NewObj(X)  _Generic(((X*)0), struct Person*: create_person(), struct Car*: create_car())
```

The simplified resulting code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Car;
struct Person;

struct Car* create_car(void) {
    puts("Create a car");
    return NULL;
}

struct Person* create_person(void) {
    puts("Create a person");
    return NULL;
}

#define NewObj(X)  _Generic(((X*)0), struct Person*: create_person(), struct Car*: create_car())

int main(void)
{
    struct Car *car = NewObj(struct Car);
    struct Person *person = NewObj(struct Person);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints as expected:

```
Create a car
Create a person
```

Anyway, I suggest calling `create_car()`/`create_person()` directly as it is more readable.

Comment: thanks for this -- what does the `0` do? `_Generic(((X*)0),...)` ?

Comment: @David542, it's just setting to `NULL` from `stdlib.h`. C standard says that for any type `T`, `(T*)0 == NULL`.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation! But why's it necessary to do that cast then? Will it not work without it?

Comment: @David542, one has to create a value of a `type` that can be dispatched with `_Generic`. `NULL` is type `void*`. Using `(X){0}` is doable but will not work for incomplete types. (`{0}` is universal initializer. Note that there is no definition of Car/Person in the code. IMO, using NULL pointer to `X` was the most robust option.

Comment: Oh! I see the issue, it's so you can pass `struct Car` to the function instead of having to define it before and pass that variable to it. So you can do `func(struct Car)` and it will essentially pass it to generic as `struct Car NULL`. Is that correct?

Comment: @David542, no you cannot pass `struct Car` to the function. If `X` is `struct Car` then `(X*)0` is like a value produced by `struct Car *value = NULL;`. This value is passed to `_Generic`. The compiler looks on the type, which is `struct Car*` and selects a proper *expression* from the selection list. See that `struct Car*` maps to `create_car()`. As result `NewObj(struct Car)` becomes `create_car()`.